# How to click button class in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How to click in this button in selenium?

```
<li title="Next Page" tabindex="0" class="ant-pagination-next" aria-disabled="false">
    <button class="ant-pagination-item-link" type="button" tabindex="-1">
        <span role="img" aria-label="right" class="anticon anticon-right">
           <svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" data-icon="right" 
           width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. [Please do not post pictures of code.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.ant-pagination-item-link").click()
```

Just target the class name ant-pagination-item-link and click it.

Furthermore using webdriver waits we get the following. This allows for the site to load until the element is clickable and click it.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,60)    
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.ant-pagination-item-link"))).click()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can try the below code

```
class_element= driver.find_element_by_class('ant-pagination-item-link')
class_element.click()
```